# Align multiple lines of TextViews and edit text

Tags: android, text, alignment, edit

I would like to make a questionnaire-like page, where the user compiles some fields.

For example:

name:  editText

last name: editText

address: editText

My intent is to have in each line a textview on the left aligned with an edit text to the right, and so on for every field i need compiled.

As long as now this is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:ignore="UselessLeaf" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twNome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Nome: " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNome"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:ems="10"
        >


    </EditText>
```

Comment: And what are you getting? What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

Better usability would be to not use any TextViews for generic text display and instead use the editext's `android:hint` xml attribute which as the docs say:

> Hint text to display when the text is empty.

From : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint

An example of how this appears can be found on twitter's screenshot :https://lh4.ggpht.com/_HN_x9NnI4cFbIZv8dTBuY7CI9P62txIjEhNEnlolHQOY9bLPtuI0LpNbDrWtCpf1JyT=h900-rw

See the bottom part where it says "Reply to Elaine Filadelfo"

So something like :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editNome"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Nome: " 
    >
```

Another examples of this pattern,

1. see the search form field at the top of this page, notice how it says "search" in gray and disappears as you focus/tap/click on it
2. http://androidniceties.tumblr.com/

Comment: I agree. Use hints. You'll save yourself a ton of work plus it's more standard to do that now. The users will love it!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer :)
I did it and it's even better than how i thought :)

Another little question: What widget should i use if i want the user to prompt his physical height?

I would like to do a scrollable selection where the height (in centimeters) is displayed.


Thanks again :)